# PostgreSQL change the data directory

Tags: linux, database, postgresql

I'm on Debian 8 and want to have another than the default directory for my databases. I have a vanilla install of PostgreSQL 9.4 (so no user databases yet).
I found this http://climber2002.github.io/blog/2015/02/07/install-and-configure-postgresql-on-ubuntu-14-dot-04/ about configuring a new data directory. Is this the correct way for doing this (or not)?

Thanks.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28926/moving-postgresql-data-to-different-drive

Answer (score 11):

Yes. Stop the server `service postgresql stop`, create the new directory and `chown` it to postgres, edit `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf` changing `data_directory` to the new directory. Initiate the directory with `initdb -D /new_dir` and then restart the postgresql server.